# Add full directory structure to Visual Studio 2010 c++ project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I want to make a C++ project from existing code. I want to show the full directory structure in Solution Explorer. I have tried using New/Project From Existing Code but that creates a flat structure. I have done this with VS 2008 but can't seem to get 2010 to work.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588734/add-folders-in-a-visual-c-project (still no fun)