# How to use folders in visual studio c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My Problem is that in the sln view, there are no folders, severely hindering organization, and in folder view, when I add c++ files they become misc files and are not added to the solution. So my question is; how would I use folders, or if it isn't possible, what should I use instead? I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add project folders and/or files:

The quickest way that I know of is to

- add the folder to your project file directory using Windows Explorer
- find the folder in Solution Explorer (make sure Show All Files is checked)
- right click on the folder and select Include In Project

You may have to do the folder and the files separately, but you can select multiple files at once.

Referencing source for [this thread of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10609293/11471113).